# Computing truncated mean between two forward indicators

Tags: c++, vector, forward

I have already computed the truncated mean of a vector via the function **truncated_mean(std::vector& v, double trimming fraction)**. This function takes as inputs the vector v and the fraction that we want to remove to calculate the mean (e.g. 10% so we remove the highest and lowest 10% values and then we compute the mean), I created it using the Standard Library.

For example, v = [0,1,2....,9], then truncated_mean(v, 0.10) = 4.5.

Now, I want to reuse the same function but instead of having v as input, I want to have 2 forward iterators, v.begin() and v.end(). I am provided with the template of typename **forward** that I should use to check if its value_type (accessed via std::iterator_traits) meets a certain criteria. My understanding of the problem is that first I need to check if the inputs belong to a vector and from there I should access the vector in itself to compute the truncated mean.

How can I adapt my function to take as input the beginning and end of the vector rather than the vector itself?

Comment: Mabe you want `truncated_mean<typename T>(const t::iterator& begin, const T:iterator& end, double d)` ?  Is your input guaranteed to be sorted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming sequence passed in is sorted you could simply use `std::distance` to figure out the length and skip the appropriate number of elements at the start and the end:

**Edit:** Extended code to use `std::accumulate` for random access iterators; Use concepts instead of distinguishing iterator types vis additional parameter, if you're allowed to use C++20 features.

```
template<typename RandomAccessIterator>
double truncated_mean_impl(RandomAccessIterator begin, RandomAccessIterator end, double trimming_fraction, std::random_access_iterator_tag)
{
    if (trimming_fraction < 0)
    {
        throw std::range_error("trimming_fraction must not be negative");
    }
    if(trimming_fraction >= 0.5)
    {
        return std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN(); // no elements left after trimming
    }

    auto const count = std::distance(begin, end);
    auto const skippedElementCountFront = static_cast<decltype(count)>(count * trimming_fraction);
    auto const summandCount = count - 2 * skippedElementCountFront;

    return std::accumulate<RandomAccessIterator, double>(begin + skippedElementCountFront, end - skippedElementCountFront, 0) / summandCount;
}


template<typename ForwardIterator>
double truncated_mean_impl(ForwardIterator begin, ForwardIterator end, double trimming_fraction, std::forward_iterator_tag)
{
    if (trimming_fraction < 0)
    {
        throw std::range_error("trimming_fraction must not be negative");
    }
    if(trimming_fraction >= 0.5)
    {
        return std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN(); // no elements left after trimming
    }

    auto const count = std::distance(begin, end);

    auto const skippedElementCountFront = static_cast<decltype(count)>(count * trimming_fraction);
    
    // skip elements in the front
    for (auto i = skippedElementCountFront; i != 0; --i, ++begin) {}

    auto const summandCount = count - 2 * skippedElementCountFront;

    double sum = 0;

    for (auto i = summandCount; i != 0; --i, ++begin)
    {
        sum += *begin;
    }

    return sum / summandCount;
}

template<typename ForwardIterator>
double truncated_mean(ForwardIterator begin, ForwardIterator end, double trimming_fraction)
{
    return truncated_mean_impl<ForwardIterator>(begin, end, trimming_fraction, typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIterator>::iterator_category());
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> const values  { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    std::cout << truncated_mean(values.cbegin(), values.cend(), 0.1) << '\n';
}
```

If the input sequence is not sorted and you cannot or don't want to sort the input copying the elements to a new vector and applying your original algorithm to this vector would probably be best.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That's the reasoning I was looking for!  Do you think it's possible to implement with any explicit loop (for)? I didn't use any loop in my original truncated_mean but that is because I already had my full vector as input.

Comment: @Rigtee Could you elaborate on why you don't consider the code to use an "explicit loop"? For loops are used in the code to skip irrelevant elements at the start and to sum up the the elements in the relevant range.

Comment: Your code used explicit loops, i.e. for-loops to skip elements and increment the sum. Actually that was part of the exercise I had to do: fine with loop but better without any explicit loop (take it as a challenge).

Comment: @Rigtee Added a specialized version for random access iterators.